# i want to learn Xml parsing in objective C for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

what are the basic things shall i read to understand how parsing xml in Objective-C works

Comment: Maybe the most basic thing is to google "iphone xml parse".

Comment: Being able to spell the language you're trying to learn is always a good start in my opinion.

Comment: @Unknown : Who so ever are down voting the question. Just think before that a fresher might have asked the question. who really doesn't know about the objective-c & iOS. He (means I) have posted the question when started learning the programming. If you go through question correctly I have never asked the code to do xml parsing. I have asked links to learn the parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HI,
  These links may help for you,

[IPhone XML Parsing](http://4arrowsmedia.com/2010/06/iphone-xml-parsing/)
[XML parsing](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

Answer (score 0):

go through these tutorials

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp

This tutorial for Internet data transferring and receiving
http://www.json.org/

and NSXMLParser class reference
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

[Xml Parsing](http://www.hivestudio.cat/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=60%3axml-parser-for-iphone&catid=35%3atechnical-note-category&Itemid=76)